# UIAStaticText Appium iOS - NodeJS

Tags: ios, node.js, appium

I am currently writing Appium automation tests in NodeJS for iOS.  Although I am having issues with UIAStaticText elements.  Even though they are visible on screen I constantly get ElementNotFound error.

I am using the XPath for the element displayed in Appium Inspector - it is in the format "//UIAApplication/UIAWindow/UIAStaticText[1]" In the app code the element is a UIALabel.

I'm trying to get the value of the label but currently unable to getAttribute but it can't find the element.

Is there a known limitation with UIAStaticText elements and is there a workaround?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking how to get an attribute or how to properly find an element. I'll assume find an element.

I'm not sure of any known issues with UIAStaticText but I would try using the following line

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAStaticText[contains(@text, '*Static Text*')]"));`

or

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAStaticText[contains(@label, '*label Text*')]"));`

This way you are not depending on the previous items within the xpath. A good way to test if you have a good xpath is to use the `copy xml` button in the appium inspector and see if your xpath returns a unique item.

In most cases I have run into the label matches the name or the text.

Hope that answers your question.